# Python 3.9 datatable to.csv() gives error when I use sep argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, datatable, export-to-csv

I'm trying to write python code for saving datatable Frame to .csv with semicolon as separator.

When I try to do that I receive error.
The issue is not present when I use fread function.
Also, to_csv() works well when separator is not specified.
According to documentation to_csv() should take sep as argument.

Error:
`Method datatable.Frame.to_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument sep`

My code (df is a pandas data frame):

```
import datatable as dt
...
dtf = dt.Frame(df)
dtf.to_csv('test.csv', sep=';')
```

Win10

Python version: 3.9.13

datatable version: 1.0.0

Thank you for help

Comment: Why convert the `df` to a `datatable`? Pandas can export directly to a CSV with `df.to_csv()`.

Comment: Performance reasons. I have huge file and datatable is faster. Unfortunately I need .csv and cannot use any other format.

Comment: @Seto Its likely that your data already contains semi colon `;` that's why you can not use it as separator.

Comment: @ThePyGuy, if this is the reason, the error message about unexpected keyword argument is grossly misleading.

Comment: @buran oh yeah, I didn't notice it earlier. Its likely that the version doesn't have `sep` argument, but need to look at the version specific docs

Comment: @ThePyGuy, I've checked with new df where there are only numbers and the error still appears.

Comment: Try passing the seperator without keyword: `dtf.to_csv('test.csv', ';')`

Comment: Now there's ```Method datatable.Frame.to_csv() takes only one positional argument, but 2 were given ```

Answer (score 0):

As @ThePyGuy suggested in the comments I've checked documentation of different versions of the package and it seems that all separator was introduced in v1.1.0 which is still on development.

Thank you for guiding me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).